# Org agenda remove todo in bulk

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, todo

In org agenda mode, select several items, mark them with `m`, then set the todo status `B t` to none. Normally I can remove TODO status with `t SPC` but `B t SPC` isn't permitted.

Answer (score 3):

After a glance at the code I think the 'fast-todo-selection' does not go together with agenda bulk marked items, yet.

Possibly you want to file a report on the org mode mailing list so the issue might be addressed.

As workaround I propose to customize variable `org-agenda-bulk-custom-functions` via `M-x customize-variable`.

You can use `SPC` as character and `(lambda nil (org-agenda-todo ""))` as function.

With this setting `B SPC` removes the todo states of the marked items AFAICS.

Comment: This seems to work, thanks. `(setq org-agenda-bulk-custom-functions '((?\s (lambda nil (org-agenda-todo "")))))`

Comment: N.B. The `?\s` part specifies the character. e.g. `?C` would make `C` the character to be pressed instead.